# how to use config file from a subdirectory while it is been kept at root directory in PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a web application. contents are:

- root dir (/var/www/)

**config.php**

index.php

details.php

- admin dir (/var/www/admin)

admin.php

I have included config.php file into index.php, details.php in root directory using require_once('config.php') as this file contains database passwords, styles, images directory paths..

how can i include that config files in my admin/admin.php file so that one config file can be used in anywhere(even in subdirectories) of my web application. Will it make any difference for the value of `define('APP_BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));` when same config file is used by all files in the web application.

if i am wrong somewhere then please get me right.

Comment: Though your question is quite unclear. I can't get it right. Just answered to `how can that config file be used anywhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update after clarification in comments:** You are looking for a way to include a central configuration file from anywhere in your project's folder structure.

@Col. Shrapnel shows one way, `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. It's the only way to use an "absolute" path from a nested folder structure. It has the limitation I describe above, but it's fine otherwise.

If you want maximum portability (i.e. the possibility to run the app with e.g. `www.example.com/myapp/version_1` as its root directory), you would have to use relative references from within your folder structure to "climb down" to the config file, e.g. `../../config.php` that will work reliably too, although be a bit cumbersome e.g. if you move a script to a different folder and you have to update the relative path.

Comment: the only problem left is how to include that "central setup file" :)

Comment: as for the files below document root, I am happily using `dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/cfg.php';` for the one level below.

Comment: what is the proper way to set a manual base path. not using DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: @Col re your first comment: True, I'm not entirely clear what the OP's question is. re your second comment: That's not the point - it's about being able to run an application in an arbitrary sub-directory as the root directory. But we have had this discussion before, I think in this question we simply have different schools of thought :)

Comment: @Idle please clarify what exactly your question is. How to get hold of the central config file, or how to define a base path *in* that central config file?

Comment: okay.. how to use a single configuration file from everywhere

Comment: okay! i get it.. now 2nd part of the question.. does the output for dirname(__FILE__) will change or remain same in such circumstances? i.e. if config file is included from some other directory.

Comment: @idle no, `dirname(__FILE__)` will always remain constant, as it always points to the current file (**not** the file that was requested, but physically the file the line is in.)

Comment: @idlecool forget this constant. It has absolutely no use. It's just another way to use *relative* path. Not an option. It can be used if you need a file which is *near* this one. But not to include main config file

Comment: @Col it *is* an option if used *in* the central configuration file to define the app's root path. That works fine, because it's always relative to the config file. It is not an option in the file that includes the config file, that's true.

Comment: It's again a story AFTER you include your config.

Comment: @Col yup, that is understood. (Read the 5th last comment, this was a follow-up question by the OP)

Comment: so i will replace define('STYLES_PATH', dirname(__FILE__)."/styles");
with define('STYLES_PATH', "/styles"); in the config.php file, now will that give the same output when config.php is included form else where in the subdirectories? i wonder dirname(__FILE__) is the option.

Comment: LOL that web/filesystem mess again. We desperately need a good FAQ article on this topic. @Idlecool output would **not** be the same. If it's a directory for the CSS files which will be called from HTML code, **only** `/styles` would work.

Answer (score 3):

If your server properly configured, just

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php";
```

anywhere

You have also 2 other possible ways.

- a Front controller setup, where ALL user requests going into one file. And ths one going to include all others from their subdirectories. Personally I don't like it cause this front file become a mess. Though it's widely used.
- I decided not to mention it because noone would use a hardcoded full path anyway.

Comment: @Pekka Just poor Thomas' one but with proper path

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can use the same config file every time... using "/" will take you back to the root directory... so in admin/admin.php use this:</strike>

`require_once("/config.php");`

you can use "../" to take you up one directory eg:

`require_once("../config.php");`

was this what you were looking for?

Comment: whats the problem with it? its always worked for me, for instance when using multiple languages as directories (eg: http://mywebsite.com/en/index.html) using / always seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: no, you have never used it. if you will try it now, you will get `File not found` error. Because there is no file config.php in the /, it's in the /var/www

Comment: @Thomas you are confusing Web URLs (which indeed work this way) and absolute filesystem paths (which don't.)

Comment: edit: @Pekka... thanks for explaining... not quite sure what the difference is

Comment: i kinda understand now... so php will see / as the COMPLETE root of the webserver? I appologise... i assumed that php would work the same as that code.

Comment: @Thomas when you `include()` a file inside PHP, this will work with absolute filesystem paths. A server's filesystem path is never identical with a web site's web root, it will look somthing like this: `/var/www/htdocs/www.example.com` (Update, yes your last comment is correct.)

Comment: right, ok i see. :) sorry - just assumed the technique was transferable.